# Job Scheduler not getting triggered at times

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-jobscheduler

Job Scheduler doesn't trigger when battery goes below 15% . Is there any way to override the battery issue. The device is only to be used for a particular app and nothing else would be running.

The device is Lenovo Tab 3 A7-10 and running on Android Lollipop(5.0.1).

```
jobScheduler.schedule(new JobInfo.Builder(MY_JOB_ID,
                new ComponentName(applicationContext, MyJob.class))
                .setPeriodic(syncInterval)
                .build());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per [Android Developers Documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0.html#jobscheduler),

```
JobInfo.isRequireBatteryNotLow()
```

states that:

*Job does not run if the battery level is at or below the criticial threshold; this is the level at which the device shows the Low battery warning system dialog.*

Also,

```
setRequiresBetteryNotLow(boolean batteryNotLow)
```

[here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setRequiresBatteryNotLow(boolean)) states that:

*Specify that to run this job, the device's battery level must not be low. This defaults to **false**. If **true**, the job will only run when the **battery level is not low**, which is generally the point where the user is given a "**low battery**" warning.*

Unfortunately, for below API 26, there is lesser access with JobScheduler and how you can use it. Probably you might not be able to use the methods I mentioned, below API 26. You can find supportive proof here: [Android JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html#js)

[Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-) serves as a JobScheduler-compatibility layer for apps targeting versions of Android lower than 5.0 (API level 21). I am not sure if it would allow you to achieve your desired scenario but have a look at it.

Thanks @ianhanniballake for improvements in the answer and drawing attention to this.

Comment: That API was added in API 26 and is not applicable to an API 21 device unfortunately.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Android Developer Documentation has clarification for this here: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html#js

Comment: @ianhanniballake I also read the documentation for the same. Is there any way to do the same in API 21 ?

Comment: @JatinJha - they added the API is API 26 because there isn't a way to do it before that.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Android Framework JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0.html#jobscheduler)

```
JobInfo.isRequireBatteryNotLow()
```

*Job does not run if the battery level is at or below the criticial threshold; this is the level at which the device shows the Low battery warning system dialog.*

[Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-)

*Firebase JobDispatcher*    **Minimum API 9**   *Requires Google Play* **Yes**  JobScheduler     Custom retry strategies **Yes**